# Solving a system of equations with a free variable

Tags: linear-algebra

Write down a system of equations and solve for $\vec{r}$.

Given:

$\vec{T}=\vec{r}\times\vec{F}$

$\vec{T}=<0,0,10>, \vec{F}=<12,5,0>$

This is the solution my prof gave to me:

(I don't know how to format the cross product here but essentially we got this while computing it)

$\vec{r}=<r_x,r_y,r_z>$

$\vec{r}\times\vec{F}=-5r_z \hat{i}+12r_z\hat{j}+(5r_x-12r_y)\hat{k}$

Next he said to set each part of the cross product equal to the corresponding parts of $\vec{T}$:

$-5r_z=0$

$12r_z=0$

So $r_z=0$

$(5r_x-12r_y)=10$

$r_x=\frac{12r_y+10}{5}=\frac{12r_y}{5}+2$

Then he wrote down:

$<r_x,r_y,r_z> = <12/5,1,0>t + <2,0,0>=<12,5,0>t+<2,0,0>$

Sorry for the bad formatting on the last part. But this is the part I am confused about. He also wrote down $r_y=r_y$ but I don't know where he got that from. Can someone please explain this to me?

Also I understand the concept of free variables but I've learned it in terms of matrices. So if I solve a system of equations and have a row of zeroes then the corresponding variable is the free variable. i.e. the variable that don't correspond to pivots in their augmented matrix. But I don't understand it in this context.

Comment: If you understand it with matrices, this is the same as $\begin{pmatrix}0&0&-5\\ 0&0&12 \\ 5& -12 & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}r_x\\ r_y\\ r_z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 10\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: hmm im kind of confused as to how you got that. how can you determine that $r_y$ is a free variable based off that matrix? also how did my prof get $r_y=r_y$?

Comment: Do you really mean $r_y=r_y$??

Comment: @Paul not sure what you're saying. it's just what my prof wrote on the board but i don't know where he got that part from. i understand where he got the other solutions

Comment: @Gribouillis should i get that matrix into rref form?

Comment: Why not? It is almost already in rref form.

Comment: If $r_y=r_y$ you are saying something is itself. In @Gribouillis matrix form the augmented matrix and swap the first and last rows. Now can you see why $r_y$ is free?